# Арканоид. Как сделать, чтобы мячик отскакивал от платформы-эллипса и адекватно разбивал кирпичи?

Tags: java, алгоритм, intellij-idea, разработка-игр

Платформа обязательно должна быть эллипсом, по прямой вертикально упавший мячик отскакивать не должен. Чтобы понять, коснулся ли мячик платформы(Pad), пытаюсь измерить расстояние от неё до мячика, но почему-то на его касания код реагирует очень редко и  в этих случаях мячик зависает в верхнем левом углу, отладить никак не могу, + бьюсь над стеной, которую должен разбивать мячик, там проблемы с отскоками и точками касания, я в панике убрала верхнюю часть стены, взаимодействие мячика с которой наладить не удалось, я не знаю, как эти функции делать.

Если расстояние от мячика до платформы нулевое, то пытаюсь найти касательную и перпендикуляр к ней, сделать из этого систему координат, перевести в неё координаты точек и вектор скорости мячика, в ней же отразить относительно перпендикуляра к касательной этот вектор и вернуть в обычную систему координат, но всё идёт как-то не так, я даже не знаю, правильно ли он отразился бы, если мог взаимодействовать с платформой

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(500,500);

        Field field = new Field(250, 400, jf.getWidth(), jf.getHeight());
        jf.add(field);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        Thread fieldThread = new Thread(field);
        fieldThread.start();
        jf.addMouseMotionListener(new FieldMouseListener(field, field.pad));

    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ball {
    public static final int RADIUS = 10;
    public static final int ACCELERATION = 2;

    public double x;
    public double y;
    private double speed_x;
    public double speed_y;
    private Color color;
    private Field field;

    public Ball(int x, int y, Field field) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.speed_x = 200;
        this.speed_y = 200;
        Random random = new Random();
        color = new Color(
                random.nextInt(224),
                random.nextInt(224),
                random.nextInt(224)
        );
        this.field = field;
    }

   // public void setSpeed(int next_x, int next_y) {
       // this.speed_x = 10000;
       // this.speed_y = 10000;

   // }

    public void move() {
        x += speed_x * Field.TIME_DELTA / 1000.;
        y += speed_y * Field.TIME_DELTA / 1000.;
        speed_x += (speed_x >= 0 ? 1 : -1) * ACCELERATION * Field.TIME_DELTA / 1000.;
        speed_y += (speed_y >= 0 ? 1 : -1) * ACCELERATION * Field.TIME_DELTA / 1000.;
        if (x < RADIUS || x > field.getWidth() - RADIUS)
            speed_x *= -1;
        if (y < RADIUS || y > field.getHeight() - RADIUS)
            speed_y *= -1;

        Point TouchPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        if(field.pad.checkTouch(x, y, RADIUS, TouchPoint))
        {
            System.out.print("o");
            rebound(TouchPoint);
        }
        else if(TouchPoint.x == -1111)
            speed_y*=-1;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval((int) x - RADIUS, (int) y - RADIUS, 2 * RADIUS, 2 * RADIUS);
    }

    public void rebound(Point TouchPoint)
    {
        //y=kx+b
        double c = 20/2;
        double d = 100/2;
        double k = (-1)* TouchPoint.getX()*d*d/TouchPoint.getY()/c/c;
        double b = d*d/TouchPoint.getY();
        double y = Math.sin(Math.atan(k+b))*speed_y;
        double x= Math.cos(Math.atan(k+b))* speed_x ;
        double tg = y/x;
        tg = Math.tan(Math.PI/2 - Math.atan(tg));
        speed_x = Math.cos(Math.atan(tg))*x;
        speed_y = Math.sin(Math.atan(tg))*y;
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Pad {
    public int padX;
    public  int padY;

    public final int padWidth = 100;
    public final int padHeight = 20;

    private Color color;
    private Field field;

    public Pad(int x, int y, Field f)
    {
        this.padX = x;
        this.padY = y+padHeight/2;
        this.field = f;

        Random random = new Random();
        color = new Color(
                random.nextInt(224),
                random.nextInt(224),
                random.nextInt(224)
        );
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(padX-(padWidth/2), padY-(padHeight/2), padWidth, padHeight);
    }


    private double getA(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
    {
        if(((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))>=-500 && ((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))<=500)
        return ((y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
        else return -1111;
    }

    public boolean checkTouch(double bX, double bY, int r, Point tp)
    {
        double a = getA(padX, padY, bX, bY);
        if(a!=1111.0) {
            double c = padHeight / 2;
            double d = padWidth / 2;
            double touchPointXX = c * c * (1 - (a * a * bX * bX / d / d));

            if (Math.abs((bX - padX) * (bX - padX) + (bY - padY) * (bY - padY)
                    - r * r - touchPointXX - a * a * touchPointXX) <= 2) {
                tp.setLocation(Math.sqrt(touchPointXX), a * Math.sqrt(touchPointXX));
                System.out.println("j");
                return true; }
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            tp.x=-1111;
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Brick  {
    public static int width;
    public  static int height;
    private static int solidity;
    public static int hpLeft;
    public boolean enabled;

    public  Color color;
    public Brick()
    {
     enabled = true;
    }



    public void setParam(int solidity, int w, int h, Color darkGray) {
        this.width =w;
        this.height = h;

        this.color = darkGray;
        this.solidity = solidity;
        this.hpLeft = solidity;
    }

    public boolean getDamage()
    {
        if(this.enabled) {
            --hpLeft;


            Color colorBuf = new Color((color.getRed() - color.getRed() / solidity),
                    (color.getGreen() - color.getGreen() / solidity),
                    (color.getBlue() - color.getBlue() / solidity));
            color = colorBuf;
            colorBuf = null;
            if (hpLeft == 0)
                return true;
        }
                return false;


    }



}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Wall extends JPanel {
    Random random;
    public int wall_x;
    public int wall_y;
    public Brick bricks[][]= new Brick[8][4];
   ;

    public Wall(int w, int h)//w и h окна
    {
        random = new Random();
        for(int i= 0; i<8; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                bricks[i][j]=new Brick();
                int hp = random.nextInt(3);
                ++hp;
                Color color;
                switch(hp) {
                    case 2: color = Color.GREEN;
                    break;
                    case 3: color = Color.MAGENTA;
                    break;
                    default: color =Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
                    break;
                }
                bricks[i][j].setParam(hp, w / 8, h / 10 / 4, color);
            }
        }

        this.wall_x=0;
        this.wall_y=w/10/2;
    }

    public void destroyBrick(int i, int j)
    {
        bricks[i][j].enabled=false;

    }



    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        int j=3;
        for(int i= 0; i<8; ++i) {
            //for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                if(bricks[i][j].hpLeft!=0) {
                    g.setColor(bricks[i][j].color);
                    g.fillRect(wall_x + bricks[i][j].width * i, wall_y + bricks[i][j].height * j,
                            bricks[i][j].width - 3, bricks[i][j].height - 3);
                }
           // }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class FieldMouseListener implements MouseMotionListener  {
    private Field field;
    private Pad pad;

    public FieldMouseListener(Field field, Pad pad) {
        this.field = field;
        this.pad = pad;
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            pad.padX = e.getX();
            //System.out.println("i");
            field.repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        pad.padX = e.getX();
       // System.out.println("i");
        field.repaint();
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Field extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    public static final int TIME_DELTA = 10;

    public Ball ball;
    public Pad pad;
    public Wall wall;

    public Field(int BallX, int Bally, int w, int h) {
        super(true);
        ball = new Ball(BallX, Bally, this);
        pad = new Pad( (int)ball.x, (int)ball.y+ball.RADIUS, this);
        wall = new Wall(w, h);

    }

    public void checkBricks()
    {//на первое время стоит нижний край,


        if(Math.abs((ball.y-ball.RADIUS)-(wall.wall_y+wall.bricks[0][0].height*4))<=1)//здесь может быть ошибка по координатам, возможно, радиус надо вычитать
        {
           System.out.println("k");
           if( wall.bricks[(int)(ball.x/wall.bricks[0][0].width)]
                       [(int)((ball.y-ball.RADIUS)/wall.bricks[0][0].height-
                   (wall.wall_y)/wall.bricks[0][0].height)-1].getDamage())
           {
               System.out.println("p");
               wall.destroyBrick((int)(ball.x/wall.bricks[0][0].width),
                      (int)((ball.y-ball.RADIUS)/wall.bricks[0][0].height-
                           (wall.wall_y/wall.bricks[0][0].height))-1);
               wall.repaint();
           }
           if( wall.bricks[(int)(ball.x/wall.bricks[0][0].width)]
                   [(int)((ball.y-ball.RADIUS)/wall.bricks[0][0].height-
                   (wall.wall_y)/wall.bricks[0][0].height)-1].hpLeft!=0)
           ball.speed_y*=-1;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            ball.paint(g);
            pad.paint(g);
            wall.paint(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
                ball.move();
                checkBricks();
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(TIME_DELTA);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь конкретизировать вопрос. Сейчас в нем слишком много лишнего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть мы знаем вектор скорости мяча `VBall` (видимо, это `(speedx, speedy)`) и единичный вектор нормали к поверхности `N`. После отражения один из компонентов вектора скорости в системе, заданной нормалью, меняет знак на противоположный, другой компонент остаётся прежним. С использованием скалярного произведения:

```
dot = speedx * n.x + speedy * n.y
```

Вектор скорости после отражения

```
newspeedx = speedx - 2 * dot * n.x
newspeedy = speedy - 2 * dot * n.y
```

Единичная нормаль к эллипсу с полуосями `a,b` в точке со смещением `dx, dy` от его центра:

```
 n.x = b*b*dx / sqrt((b*b*dx)^2+(a*a*dy)^2)
 n.y = a*a*dy / sqrt((b*b*dx)^2+(a*a*dy)^2)
```

И ещё - проверка на каждом шаге столкновения двух объектов с известными траекториями   - не очень хорошая идея. Рано или поздно возникнет ситуация с тем, что будет заметно, как будто мячик частично проник в стену или ракетку. Лучше рассчитывать момент столкновения заранее, и обрабатывать столкновение точно в это момент. Но пока это не так важно.